# location.reload(); is delayed on remote server (locally works instantly)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Everything works like a charm locally when red block hits black block, it refreshes instantly (coming to start position). I can't figure out why the website doesn't refresh after collision (game over) on the remote server. Sometimes it needs few seconds to react or it requires moving the player position.

Found a tip to replace 
**location.reload(true);** 
with 
**location.href = location.href;** 
but it doesn't work at all in my case.

Fiddle to inspect my code: https://jsfiddle.net/32o8q5gz/1/ 
Remote host: https://stacho163.000webhostapp.com/

HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Obulis 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gameStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game-content">
        <h1>Obulis 2</h1>
        <canvas id="game-window">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="gameScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
}

.game-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 1.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

#game-window {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw * 16/9;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -46%);
    background-color: gray;
}
```

JS code:

```
    // js game script //
let canvas = document.getElementById('game-window');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let left = false;
let up = false;
let right = false;
let down = false;

let player = {
    size: 50,
    posX: (canvas.width / 2) - 25,
    posY: (canvas.height / 2) - 25,
    speed: 5
}

let obstacle = {
    size: Math.round((Math.random() * 100) + 50),
    posX: Math.round((Math.random() * 1200) + 50),
    posY: -50,
    speed: Math.round((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
}

function drawPlayer() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(player.posX, player.posY, player.size, player.size);
}

function drawObstacle() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(obstacle.posX, obstacle.posY, obstacle.size, obstacle.size);
    obstacle.posY += obstacle.speed;
}

function darknessCollision() {
    if (player.posX < 0 || 
        player.posY < 0 ||         
        player.posX > canvas.width - player.size ||
        player.posY > canvas.height - player.size) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}

function obstacleCollision() {
    if (player.posX <= obstacle.posX + obstacle.size && 
        player.posY <= obstacle.posY + obstacle.size &&
        player.posX + player.size >= obstacle.posX && 
        player.posY + player.size >= obstacle.posY) {
        location.href = location.href;
    }
}

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function move() {
    if (left) {
        player.posX -= player.speed;
    }
    if (up) {
        player.posY -= player.speed;
    }
    if (right) {
        player.posX += player.speed;
    }
    if (down) {
        player.posY += player.speed;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) left = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 38) up = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) right = true;
    if (e.keyCode == 40) down = true;   
    e.preventDefault();
}

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) left = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 38) up = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) right = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 40) down = false;
    e.preventDefault();
}

setInterval (function game() {
    clearCanvas();
    drawObstacle();
    drawPlayer();
    darknessCollision();
    obstacleCollision();
    move();
}, 10);
```

Thanks in advance for your tips! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a completely normal behavior.

When you refresh a local website, the only delay is the time spent reading the website again from your computer’s memory, and even that can get much faster for many reasons.

However, refreshing an online website, usually (if not cached), requires a “round trip time” from your computer to the server, which is sometimes costing few seconds.

If refreshing the page is for the sake of getting new updates, unfortunately there is no way to reduce the refreshing time. But, if you just need to start the website one more time, you can either use JavaScript history methods as mentioned, or have a JavaScript function that returns you to the first state without the need to refresh at all.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, therefore i will end it in other way, thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Two other options:

```
history.go(0);
```

And:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```